# Transitivity of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to implement a c++ solution to find whether a binary matrix of n*n elements is transitive.
This is the condition:

> A matrix M is transitive if and only if for any elements a, b, c (a !=
>   b != c) such that M[a][b] = 1 and M[b][c] = 1 the condition M[a][c] =
>   1 is true.

The output should be 1 if the matrix is transitive, otherwise, 0.

My code:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n;
    bool trans = true;
    cin >> n;

    int **m = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == 1 && m[j][i] == 1 && m[i][i] != 1)
                trans = false;
        }
    }

    if (trans)
        cout << 1;
    else
        cout << 0;
}
```

The code doesn't pass the e-judge I am trying to submit to. What can be the problem?

Comment: What have you tried to do to debug? Have you tried any specific test cases that you know do or don't work?

Comment: `if (m[i][j] == 1 && m[j][i] == 1 && m[i][i] != 1)` That's totally not what the transitivity condition says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 for loops not 2 (i, j , and k).

Comment: Could you [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58573592/edit) and add a code example? It will make your answer better!

Comment: The answer of @Najam Shah is correct but you need to add another if statement.

Comment: `if (i != j && j != k && i != k)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n;
    bool trans = true;
    cin >> n;

    int **m = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                if ((i!=j && j!=k) && !(m[i][j] == 1 && m[j][k] == 1 && m[k][i] == 1))
                    trans = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (trans)
        cout << 1;
    else
        cout << 0;
}
```

Try this code this should work fine

Comment: Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58573558/edit) to explain what changes you made. That makes your answer better!

Comment: Not quite correct:  you need to do the check only if i!=j and j!=k

Comment: Can't it be implemented only using i and j?

Comment: @Nap there are 3 variables in the definition: a,b,c and it has to work with any combination.  So 3 loops are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem states:

> `M[a][b] = 1 and M[b][c] = 1 the condition M[a][c] = 1 is true`.

Your test (paraphrased):

> `m[i][j] == 1 && m[j][i] == 1 && m[i][i] == 1`

In the problem, there are three indices. You only check with two indices. You need to loop over `i`,`j`,`k`. You also need to perform this check only when `i != j and j != k`.

So, something like this - without using naked arrays and other such silliness.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<vector>

struct int_iter {
    int val = {};
    operator int() const { return val; }
    int operator*() const { return val; }
    int_iter operator++() { val += 1; return {val}; }
};

struct range_n {
    int n;
    range_n(int n = 1) : n(n) {}
    int_iter begin() const { return {}; }
    int_iter end() const { return {n}; }
    int square() const { return n*n; }
};

int main() {
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    range_n span;
    std::cin >> span.n;

    std::vector<double> M(span.n * span.n);

    auto M_at = [&M,span](int i, int j)->auto& {return M[i*span.n + j];};

    for (auto i : span)
        for (auto j : span)
            std::cin >> M_at(i, j);

    for (auto i : span)
        for (auto j : span)
            if (i != j && M_at(i, j) == 1)
                for (auto k : span)
                    if (j != k && M_at(j, k) == 1 && M_at(i, k) != 1)
                    {
                        std::cout << 0 << std::endl;
                        return 1;
                    }

    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```